# Temporarily store data in form and save to file

Tags: c#, save

I have a multi-form program that calculates numbers then displays them on labels. I'm facing a problem and its having to do with saving the information when I close a form window. I'm lost at this point, all I need is to temporarily store the data in the forms until I decide I would like to save all the information. I did my home work, learned about databinding, saving to xml and text files. I don't know what the best method for this would be. I'm chewing through the wood on my desk trying to figure out how to do this. Any info helps!

Comment: Assuming the question here is "what the best method for this would be?", it'll be whatever tickles your fancy (XML/text/json). From what you said about the information being displayed as labels, there isn't too much information to save so it shouldn't matter too much performance-wise. I'd probably save it to a text file if the information isn't sensitive and there's not too much of it.

Comment: Make sure for each form, you have local variable to store info temporarily and text file to store permanently. Add an event trigger to save to text file when user closes the form window. Then you are all set.

Comment: Create a temp variable and store it there or if you want it to be accessible to different forms then create a singleton class for storing temp data. Unless you mean to store data when you close the application. If that's the case store it in a text file preferable in JSON format.

Comment: I think you might be thinking about this the wrong way. What if you, instead of storing the data in a form, only present it in the form. I.e. Whenever a field is changed you save the data to a file. That way you wouldn't have to worry about loosing any data.

Comment: I was just thinking what if I used my Form1 to store variables from the other two forms. Then find away to call them. That way when the two other forms close and then I can just open them back up with the edited info. I have no clue how to do this though.